# How to use class variable into another class in python

Tags: python-2.7, bluetooth

Following is a code to detect low energy bluetooth devices and store there BT addresses along with the timestamp in a database . there is an instance (dev) of method handleDiscovery  which stores the address I need to use this to store address to database but m having trouble connecting it to 
    BTA = ScanDelegate.dev.addr and there is an indentation error showing at create_table

```
from  bluepy.btle import DefaultDelegate,Scanner
import sqlite3
import time
import datetime
conn = sqlite3.connect('bluTry1.db')
c = conn.cursor()


class ScanDelegate(DefaultDelegate):
      def __init__(self):
          DefaultDelegate.__init__(self)

      def handleDiscovery(self,dev,isNewDev,isNewData):
          pass

scanner = Scanner().withDelegate(ScanDelegate())
devices = scanner.scan(10.0)


def create_table():
    c.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS beaconstat(BT_address TEXT,time_stamp TEXT)')


def data_entry():
    time = str(datetime.datetime.today().strftime('%H:%M:%S'))
    BTA = ScanDelegate.dev.addr
    c.execute("INSERT INTO beaconstat(BT_address , time )VALUES(?,?)",(BTA,time))
    conn.commit()

create_table()

for i in range(5):
   data_entry()
   time.sleep(1)
c.close()
conn.close()
```

Comment: Can you please paste the whole traceback? (the error you received)

Comment: File "bluTry1.py", line 20
    def create_table():
    ^
IndentationError: unexpected indent

Comment: Thx, but please add it to your question (formatted as code)

Comment: Well, i'm not awake - So you have an indentation error, from what I see I suspect you uses both tab and spaces as indentation characters. You must only uses 4 spaces as indentation.

Comment: I checked the spaces .. but error still persists.

Comment: but now it is showing that ScanDelegate has no attribute named dev

Comment: this is an another question so - please try to find the anwser yourself and create a new question if you _really_ can't find out how to fix. You could remove this question too - it's would not help anyone in the future.